# net :: ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, html, https

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que tem como objetivo mostrar vídeo e chamadas de áudio. Como uma videoconferência. Vários usuários ao mesmo tempo.

Estou usando peer.js.

Mas o seguinte erro está ocorrendo:

**GET https://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js net :: ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**

Como posso resolver isso?

Obrigado,

Fernando

Answer (score 0):

O certificado SSL do site é inválido e por isso o navegador está bloqueando.

Utilize a URL apenas com o `http` ou utilize serviços de `CDN`. Por exemplo: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/peerjs